# How to read xml from web response?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I am trying to read xml from web response and get selected nodes (i.e link) from it.  This is what  I have so far and its showing **"System.Xml.XmlElement"**, as an output.

WRequest method, sends a POST request to url using web request and returns a string xml response such as:

```
<status> <code>201</code>
<resources_created>
<link href="####" rel="############" title="####" /> 
</resources_created> 
<warnings> <warning>display_date is read-only</warning> </warnings> 
</status>
```

ReadUri2 method

```
public static string readUri2()
    {
        string uri = "";
        string xml = WRequest();

        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

        XmlNode elem = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
        uri = elem.ToString();
        return uri;

        }
```

PageLoad calls

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uri = readUri2();
        Label1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(uri);

    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.  Many thanks.

Comment: @CodeCaster: In what way is that a duplicate? How would it explain why the OP is seeing `System.Xml.XmlElement` as output?

Comment: @Jon you're right in that OP's question is _"Why do I see the type name when I call `.ToString()`"_. The question they want answered is a different one, namely the one I linked to: _"How to select a specific XML node or attribute value"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Yes, but I think it's important to go step by step... I don't think it's a duplicate question, and I think it's useful to have in its own right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The immediate problem (the reason you're seeing `System.Xml.XmlElement`) is that you're calling `ToString` on an `XmlElement`, which doesn't override that method. You probably want to use the `InnerXml` or `OuterXml` properties instead:

```
XmlNode elem = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
return elem.OuterXml;
```

That's returning the whole of the XML of the first child, which is `code`. Next you'll want to change which element you're looking for, and get the right attributes.

As a side note, I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML instead - it's a generally nicer XML API. For example:

```
// TODO: Rename the `WRequest` method; that's horrible.
var document = XDocument.Parse(WRequest());
var href = document.Descendants("link").Single().Attribute("href").Value;
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation into where I was going wrong.  Many thanks for your help.